# Missing Column in Power BI Service

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have been requested to add another column in a dataflow in Power BI and have done so and refreshed the dataset which uses the dataflow. The field is not appearing in the list of fields in Power BI for some reason. I have tried downloading the dataset on my desktop and cleared the cache and did not work. I opened Power Query (Transform data) and the column exists. I've tried to refresh preview and Close and Load but still not showing. I have 3 columns in that table in Power Query but only 2 are shown in the list of Fileds in Power BI.

Please can you help?

Power BI Filed List

[image]

Power Query

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to sort this out by right clicking the table and selecting **Refresh data**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

check whether the data source path is correct or not in PBI desktop [path is from your local machine or not]

P.S: If this answer helps, please take a moment to check the tick mark and upvote this answer.